# Change Background Color of Shiny App-- CSS

Tags: html, css, r, colors, shiny

None of the solutions for changing R shiny app background color are working for me. I'm new to CSS and HTML, so would love some help. I've tried adding "tags$style(".well {background-color:[#000000];}")," in various places of my code, as well as some other solutions i found in stackover flow, but nothing has worked.

Goal is to change the red scribbled area to black or grey. I would also be interested in changing the tabBox color, but it's not my  primary goal. See below:[image]

Here is my code for UI:

```
library('shiny')
library('shinyjs')
library('shinydashboard')

##########
header<-dashboardHeader(titleWidth = 325)
header$children[[2]]$children <-  
tags$a(tags$img(src='image.PNG',height='45',width='184'))

######
body<-dashboardBody(  tags$style(".span12 {background-color: black;}"),
                  useShinyjs(),
                  tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color: #000000}" ),
                  tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #000000}"),
                  tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #000000}"),
                  tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),

                  fluidPage(
                    #img(src="img2.PNG",height="100%", width="100%"),
                    tabBox("Menu Surf Database", width = 12,
                           tabPanel("Menu Surf Database", 
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                      tabPanel("LTO Survey results",
                                               h2(strong(textOutput("t"))),
                                               h4(textOutput("Description")),
                                               h2(strong("LTO Results"),align='center'),
                                               h4(strong(textOutput("Price"))),
                                               br(),
                                               plotOutput("Q4plot",height = 200),
                                               br(),br(),
                                               plotOutput("seasonPlot",height=200),
                                               br(),br(),
                                               plotOutput("Q1plot"),
                                               br(),br()),

                                      tabPanel("Demographics",
                                               h2(strong(textOutput("t2"))),
                                               h4(textOutput("Description2")),
                                               h2(strong("Demographics of Top Two Box:"),align='center'),
                                               h3(strong("By Purchase Intent"),align= "center"),
                                               br(),
                                               plotOutput("demoPlot1"),
                                               plotOutput("demoPlot2")
                                      ))),
                           tabPanel("Exploratory Comparison",
                                    tabsetPanel(
                                      tabPanel("Visuals",
                                               h2(strong("Proprietary Menu Surf Results:")),
                                               selectInput("index",label = "Index by:",choices = c("Meal Part","Day Part"),selected = "Meal Part",multiple = FALSE),
                                               checkboxInput("addItem", label="Include sidebar item for comparision?", value = FALSE, width = NULL),
                                               h4(strong("Purchase Intent Indices:")),
                                               plotOutput("prop1"),
                                               h4(strong("Uniqueness Indices:")),
                                               plotOutput("prop2"),
                                               h4(strong("Draw Indices:")),
                                               plotOutput("prop3"),
                                               h4(strong("Cravebility Indices:")),
                                               plotOutput("prop4"),
                                               h4(strong("Brand Fit Indices")),
                                               plotOutput("prop5")        
                                      ),
                                      tabPanel("Tables",
                                               h2(strong("Menu Surf Results, tables:")),
                                               h3("Purchase Intent"),
                                               br(),
                                               dataTableOutput("propTable1")
                                      )))
                    )))


sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(width = 325,
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "$('li.active a').first().html()==='Menu Surf Database'",
                        h4("Filters:"),
                        br(),
                        selectInput('month',label='Month:',choices= month.name,multiple = TRUE,selected = "March"),
                        selectInput("year",label= "Year:",choices= c("2017"),multiple = FALSE,selected = "2017"),
                        selectInput("daypart",label = "Day Part:",choices=c("Breakfast","Lunch/Dinner"),selected = c("Breakfast","Lunch/Dinner"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput("mealpart",label="Meal Part:",choices =c("Adult Beverage","App/Starter","Dessert","Ent/Main Dish","Non-Alcohol Beverage","Side/Extra","Snack"),selected = c("Adult Beverage","App/Starter","Dessert","Ent/Main Dish","Non-Alcohol Beverage","Side/Extra","Snack"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput("courseCategory",label = "Course Category:",choices = c('All','Asian Bowl','Baked Goods','Beef Dish','Beverage','Breaded Other',
                                                                                            'Breaded Protein','Breaded Vegetables','Breads','Breakfast Starch',
                                                                                            'Burgers','Chicken Dish','Combo Plates','Egg Dish','Fish Dish','Fried Dessert',
                                                                                            'Fries','Frozen Beverage','Ice Cream','Mexican','Mixed Grill','Nachos','Pasta/Noodles',
                                                                                            'Pizza','Pork Dish','Salad Main Dish','Sandwich','Shellfish Dish','Soup','Specialty Drinks'
                        ),selected= 'All',multiple = FALSE),
                        #textOutput('test'),
                        uiOutput('restChoices'),
                        uiOutput('itemChoices'),
                        br(),
                        h5("Edit data by demographic features below:"),
                        selectInput('gender',label = "Gender:",choices = c("Female","Male"),multiple = TRUE,selected = c("Female","Male")),
                        selectInput('generation',label = "Generation:",choices = c("Generation Z","Millennials","Generation X","Baby Boomers","Matures"),selected = c("Generation Z","Millennials","Generation X","Baby Boomers","Matures"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput('ethnicity',label ='Ethnicity:',choices = c("Asian","Black/African American (non-Hispanic)","Caucasian (non-Hispanic)","Hispanic","Mixed ethnic background","Other"),selected = c("Asian","Black/African American (non-Hispanic)","Caucasian (non-Hispanic)","Hispanic","Mixed ethnic background","Other"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput('ea',label = 'Eater Archetype:', choices = c("Affluent Socializers","Bargain Hunters","Busy Balancers","FS Hobbyist","FS Hobbyists","Functional Eater","Functional Eaters","Habitual Matures","Health Enthusiast","Health Enthusiasts"),selected = c("Affluent Socializers","Bargain Hunters","Busy Balancers","FS Hobbyist","FS Hobbyists","Functional Eater","Functional Eaters","Habitual Matures","Health Enthusiast","Health Enthusiasts"),multiple = TRUE)
                      ),
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "$('li.active a').first().html()==='Exploratory Comparison'",
                        #h5("The Exploratory Comparison tab allows you to view results for many items. Please filter for your results below."),
                        h4("Filters:"),
                        br(),
                        selectInput('month2',label='Month:',choices= month.name,multiple = TRUE,selected = "March"),
                        selectInput("year2",label= "Year:",choices= c("2017"),multiple = FALSE,selected = "2017"),
                        selectInput("daypart2",label = "Day Part:",choices=c("Breakfast","Lunch/Dinner"),selected = c("Breakfast","Lunch/Dinner"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput("mealpart2",label="Meal Part:",choices =c("Adult Beverage","App/Starter","Dessert","Ent/Main Dish","Non-Alcohol Beverage","Side/Extra","Snack"),selected = c("Adult Beverage","App/Starter","Dessert","Ent/Main Dish","Non-Alcohol Beverage","Side/Extra","Snack"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput("courseCategory2",label = "Course Category:",choices = c('All','Asian Bowl','Baked Goods','Beef Dish','Beverage','Breaded Other',
                                                                                             'Breaded Protein','Breaded Vegetables','Breads','Breakfast Starch',
                                                                                             'Burgers','Chicken Dish','Combo Plates','Egg Dish','Fish Dish','Fried Dessert',
                                                                                             'Fries','Frozen Beverage','Ice Cream','Mexican','Mixed Grill','Nachos','Pasta/Noodles',
                                                                                             'Pizza','Pork Dish','Salad Main Dish','Sandwich','Shellfish Dish','Soup','Specialty Drinks'
                        ),selected= 'All',multiple = FALSE),
                        uiOutput('restChoices2'),
                        br(),
                        h5("Edit data by demographic features below:"),
                        selectInput('gender2',label = "Gender:",choices = c("Female","Male"),multiple = TRUE,selected = c("Female","Male")),
                        selectInput('generation2',label = "Generation:",choices = c("Generation Z","Millennials","Generation X","Baby Boomers","Matures"),selected = c("Generation Z","Millennials","Generation X","Baby Boomers","Matures"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput('ethnicity2',label ='Ethnicity:',choices = c("Asian","Black/African American (non-Hispanic)","Caucasian (non-Hispanic)","Hispanic","Mixed ethnic background","Other"),selected = c("Asian","Black/African American (non-Hispanic)","Caucasian (non-Hispanic)","Hispanic","Mixed ethnic background","Other"),multiple = TRUE),
                        selectInput('ea2',label = 'Eater Archetype:', choices = c("Affluent Socializers","Bargain Hunters","Busy Balancers","FS Hobbyist","FS Hobbyists","Functional Eater","Functional Eaters","Habitual Matures","Health Enthusiast","Health Enthusiasts"),selected = c("Affluent Socializers","Bargain Hunters","Busy Balancers","FS Hobbyist","FS Hobbyists","Functional Eater","Functional Eaters","Habitual Matures","Health Enthusiast","Health Enthusiasts"),multiple = TRUE)

                      ))

########
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    header,
    sidebar,
    body
  )



###########

server<-function(input, output, session){
}

#####

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Not familiar with `R`, but only thing I can see is you are missing a `;` after declaring `background-color`...

Comment: `.container-fluid {background-color: #000;}` and `.content {background-color: #000;}` I believe

Comment: .content  {background-color: #000;} worked, thanks!!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with shiny, looks like you use css via the `tags$style(type='text/css', ".content, .container-fluid {background-color: #000;}")` lines

Comment: yes, I changed  body<-dashboardBody(  tags$style(".span12 {background-color: black;}"), to body<-dashboardBody(  tags$style(".content {background-color: black;}"),   thanks!!

Comment: so I guess you can change that to `tags$style(".span12, .content, .container-fluid {background-color: #000;}")`

Comment: the container-fluid addition did not change anything

Comment: do you have `.container-fluid` not `container-fluid`?

Comment: oh youre right, looks like container-fluid inherits from content so you only need content

Comment: Hi, working on the same app-- I want to change tabBox to a regular tab panel, but i looks the css for the background seems to be applying to the tab... anyone know if i can maintain the white of the tabpanel while still having the outside background-color black?

Comment: disregard. got what i wanted using Box( tabsetPanel (tabPanel

Answer (score 2):

With the shinyWidgets package you can change the background color with:

```
setBackgroundColor("black")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tags you can change BG color with the follow code set in dashboardBody():

```
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('/* body */.content-wrapper, .right-side {background-color: #7d848b;}')))
```